How to further optimize matrix multiplication in llm.c project?
I’m working with a matrix multiplication implementation from llm.c project, specifically from this file.
There are two implementations provided:

matmul_forward_cpu: A basic matrix multiplication loop.
matmul_forward_ngc92: An optimized version using loop unrolling and caching.

I’ve compiled these using gcc with the -Ofast flag, and the performance improvements have been impressive. Here are the results:

matmul_forward_cpu: 5.5 seconds
matmul_forward_ngc92: 2.8 seconds

Without -Ofast, the performance is much worse (more than 2 minutes), but with -Ofast, it’s clear that the compiler is applying heavy optimizations.
What I’ve Tried:
I’ve tried manually implementing AVX and NEON instructions to beat the matmul_forward_ngc92 implementation, but it seems the -Ofast flag is already applying SIMD optimizations, and I haven't been able to surpass the 2.8-second result.
My Question:
Does anyone have further suggestions on how to optimize the matmul_forward_ngc92 function, or are there specific CPU architecture features or other techniques that could further improve the performance? My goal is to push it beyond the 2.8-second mark.
One thing that comes to my mind is use OpenMP to utilize multiple cores
Code is as follows (from llm.c):
void matmul_forward_cpu(float* out,
                    const float* inp, const float* weight, const float* bias,
                    int B, int T, int C, int OC) {
    // OC is short for "output channels"
    // inp is (B,T,C), weight is (OC, C), bias is (OC)
    // out will be (B,T,OC)
    for (int b = 0; b < B; b++) {
        for (int t = 0; t < T; t++) {
            float* out_bt = out + b * T * OC + t * OC;
            const float* inp_bt = inp + b * T * C + t * C;
            for (int o = 0; o < OC; o++) {
                float val = (bias != NULL) ? bias[o] : 0.0f;
                const float* wrow = weight + o*C;
                for (int i = 0; i < C; i++) {
                    val += inp_bt[i] * wrow[i];
                }
                out_bt[o] = val;
            }
        }
    }
}

void matmul_forward_ngc92(float* out,
    const float* inp, const float* weight, const float* bias,
    int B, int T, int C, int OC) {
    // most of the running time is spent here and in matmul_backward
    // OC is short for "output channels"
    // inp is (B,T,C), weight is (OC, C), bias is (OC)
    // out will be (B,T,OC)

    // make sure the tiled loop will be correct, otherwise, fallback to slow version
    #define LOOP_UNROLL 8

    if (B * T % LOOP_UNROLL != 0) {
        printf("MUST BE A MULTIPLE OF 8"); // FIXME
        return;
    }

    // collapse the B and T loops into one and turn it into a strided loop.
    // then we can tile the inner loop, and reuse the loaded weight LOOP_UNROLL many times
    // for significant speed-ups.
    for (int obt = 0; obt < B * T; obt += LOOP_UNROLL) {
        for (int o = 0; o < OC; o++) {
            // keep LOOP_UNROLL many results in register, initialized by the bias term.
            float result[LOOP_UNROLL];
            for (int ibt = 0; ibt < LOOP_UNROLL; ++ibt) {
                result[ibt] = (bias != NULL) ? bias[o] : 0.0f;
            }

            // inner loops. Because we do LOOP_UNROLL steps of inner bt, we can cache
            // the value of weight[i + o * C] and reuse it.
            // we compile with -Ofast, so the compiler will turn the inner loop into a bunch of FMAs
            for (int i = 0; i < C; i++) {
                float w = weight[i + o * C];
                for (int ibt = 0; ibt < LOOP_UNROLL; ++ibt) {
                    int bt = obt + ibt;
                    result[ibt] += inp[bt * C + i] * w;
                }
            }

            // write back results to main memory
            for (int ibt = 0; ibt < LOOP_UNROLL; ++ibt) {
                int bt = obt + ibt;
                out[bt * OC + o] = result[ibt];
            }
        }
    }
}

Here is the test code I used.
#define NUM_KERNELS 2

void matmul_forward(int kernel_num,
    float* out,
    const float* inp, const float* weight, const float* bias,
    int B, int T, int C, int OC) {

    switch (kernel_num) {
        case 0:
            matmul_forward_cpu(out, inp, weight, bias, B, T, C, OC);
            break;
        case 1:
            matmul_forward_ngc92(out, inp, weight, bias, B, T, C, OC);
            break;
        default:
            printf("Invalid kernel number\n");
            exit(1);
    }
}


void validate_results_cpu(const float* device_result, const float* cpu_reference, const char* name, int num_elements, float tolerance);
float* make_random_float(size_t N);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    srand(0);

    int B = 8;
    int T = 1024;
    int C = 768;
    int OC = 768 * 4; // expansion of 4, e.g. in the MLP
    int RUNS = 4; // number of times to run a kernel for benchmarks

    srand(137);

    float* out = make_random_float(B * T * OC);
    float* inp = make_random_float(B * T * C);
    float* weight = make_random_float(OC * C);
    float* bias = make_random_float(OC);

    printf("> Calculating reference\n");
    matmul_forward_cpu(out, inp, weight, bias, B, T, C, OC);

    for (int kernel_num = 0; kernel_num < NUM_KERNELS; kernel_num++) {
        printf("> Verifying kernel #%d\n", kernel_num);

        srand(137);

        float* kernel_out = make_random_float(B * T * OC);
        float* kernel_inp = make_random_float(B * T * C);
        float* kernel_weight = make_random_float(OC * C);
        float* kernel_bias = make_random_float(OC);
        // float* kernel_bias = NULL;

        matmul_forward(kernel_num, kernel_out, kernel_inp, kernel_weight, kernel_bias, B, T, C, OC);

        validate_results_cpu(kernel_out, out, "out", B * T * OC, 1e-5);

        free(kernel_out);
        free(kernel_inp);
        free(kernel_weight);
        free(kernel_bias);
    }

    printf("All kernels passed! Starting benchmarks.\n\n");

    for (int kernel_num = 0; kernel_num < NUM_KERNELS; kernel_num++) {
        printf("> Running kernel #%d\n", kernel_num);
        struct timespec start, end;
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);

        for (int i = 0; i < RUNS; i++) {
            matmul_forward(kernel_num, out, inp, weight, bias, B, T, C, OC);
        }

        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);
        double time_elapsed_s = (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) + (end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec) / 1e9;
        printf("> Kernel #%d, (took %f ms)\n", kernel_num, time_elapsed_s * 1000);
    }

    // free memory
    free(out);
    free(inp);
    free(weight);
    free(bias);

    return 0;
}

float* make_random_float(size_t N) {
    float* arr = (float*)malloc(N * sizeof(float));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        arr[i] = ((float)rand() / RAND_MAX) * 2.0 - 1.0; // range -1..1
    }
    return arr;
}

void validate_results_cpu(const float* kernel_result, const float* cpu_reference, const char* name, int num_elements, float tolerance) {
    int nfaults = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_elements; i++) {
        // print the first few comparisons
        if (i < 5) {
            printf("%f %f\n", cpu_reference[i], kernel_result[i]);
        }
        float t_eff = tolerance + fabs(cpu_reference[i]);
        // ensure correctness for all elements.
        if (fabs(cpu_reference[i] - kernel_result[i]) > t_eff) {
            printf("Mismatch of %s at %d: CPU_ref: %f vs CPU_new: %f\n", name, i, cpu_reference[i], kernel_result[i]);
            nfaults++;
            if (nfaults >= 10) {
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
    }
    if (nfaults > 0) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("OK\n");
}

I tested the following options based on the suggestions, and here are the results from my system.
I ran the tests on an Apple M2 CPU with 16GB RAM.
I didn't specify the -march flag, assuming it would use the default for my system, apple-m2.



method
runtime for matmul_forward_cpu (ms)
runtime for matmul_forward_ngc92 (ms)




with -Ofast (my main method)
5,578
2,881


with restrict and -Ofast
5,587
2,869


with -O2 -fno-tree-vectorize
81,621
11,648


with -O3
55,174
11,642




2.8 seconds on what CPU model with what matrix sizes? With what -march= options? Like -march=native (on what CPU)? Is your alternative to -Ofast just nothing, i.e. a debug build? Of course that's terrible. The interesting things to compare against are -O2 -fno-tree-vectorize or -O3 (without -ffast-math).

See also https://salykova.github.io/matmul-cpu for how to get efficient SIMD asm with cache-blocking, for AVX+FMA intrinsics, with OpenMP for threading.

You may want to use -O3 instead of -Ofast because -Ofast can result in optimization that disregards strict standard compliance and can enable optimization that are not valid for all standard conforming programs (this is especially true when intrinsics are involved) In fact, -O2 turns on a majority of the optimization that provide tree and loop vectorization. -O3 adds a dozen or so additional loop optimizations.

chux has already got in with restrict, which can make important improvements for auto-vectorization. For more general help on both self implementation and tips for improving auto-vectorization outcomes, here's the Arm doc on Neon intrinsics

Didn't inspect your code in detail but this lecture might give an idea: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o7h_sYMk_oc

@Morteza, to really help others help you, append the test code here so others may try.

restrict
Given a function like:
void matmul_forward_cpu(float* out,  
    const float* inp, const float* weight, const float* bias,
    int B, int T, int C, int OC) {
  ...

The compiler is not allowed to assume the data pointed to by out does not overlap the data pointed to by inp, weight nor bias.
This restriction prevents some optimizations.  See `restrict'
If there is never overlap in various pointers' data, let the compiler know that to allow additional optimizations:
void matmul_forward_cpu_alt(float* restrict out,  
    const float* restrict inp, const float* restrict weight, const float* restrict bias,
    int B, int T, int C, int OC) {
  ...


A deep understanding of restrict is not trivial nor do compilers always use it well.  Good luck.
This applies to matmul_forward_ngc92() too.

The compiler definitely does do better Neon optimizations with restrict, so this is an important point!
